# Adapter not loading anything with SQLite C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I use this code and SQLite says "Data Source cannot be empty.  Use :memory: to open an in-memory database"

here is my code

```
 string dbfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName + "\\m23.db";

        string sql;

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("datasource="+ dbfile);

        SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from p_posts", connection);
        DataSet data = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(data); //  <<< here i get the error

        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
        cmd.Connection = connection;

        connection.Open();
```

Any help is apreciated , 
Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbfile);
```

The [examples](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite) I've seen use "Data Source" instead of "datasource".

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such parameter syntax issues you might also consider using `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder`

```
SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder con = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
con.DataSource = dbfile;
```